# C(++) Sockets fd_* is blocking/delaying write/send

Tags: c++, c, linux, sockets

I can receive and send data as long as I dont use fd_set(..) /select.
After that I can't send data to the client. The data is send "after" killing the process (pressing ctrl C).
For example if I run that snippet: 
http://www.binarytides.com/multiple-socket-connections-fdset-select-linux/
I get the "welcome client-connected message" (line 126) but after the next loop, the new client is added via fd_set and select. Line 171 should send the received message back to the client, but I only get it back **after** killing the process. 
Maybe it's because the "OS running the server" thinks that the connection is busy and buffers the output. And that could be the reason why killing the process causes the buffer to be send to client. 
If I use write() instead of send() the behavoir doesn't change. 
 int count =  write()
count is fine and the code doesn't throw any error. 
I tried it on two ubuntu 14.04 systems (one lts and some other build from source) 
If you need some more src-code I will upload it. I just think that the example in the link is well documented and shows the problem.
I already found a lot of stuff about the topic, but I can't figure out what I am doing wrong as all tutorials and docs do it that way.

Unluckily I am not that familiar with c++/linux and don't know what to investigate next. So any help is appreciated. 
Thanks :)

Comment: How are you testing? How are you determining when the data is sent? Most likely, the problem is on the other end, not checking for data until the connection closes.

Comment: Why did you tag this C++. The sources linked look like plain C.

Comment: David Schwartz: The communication works if I dont use fd_*. For example I can send and receive data if I don't use plain read() and write methods. (The client gets it)
<br>
alk:You are right, the example I posted is pure c

Answer (score 1):

My suspicion is that what you are seeing is not a network problem at all, but rather a buffering problem with your program's stdout stream.  In particular, characters your program sends to stdout won't actually become visible in the terminal window until either (a) a newline character ('\n') is printed, or (b) you manually flush the stream (e.g. vi fflush(stdout), or cout.flush(), or (c) the program terminates (as happens when you press CTRL-C).

So most likely your client program did receive and print the message, but you aren't seeing it because the program is waiting for the newline character before printing anything to the terminal.  (it makes sense to do that in cases where the program is printing out a line of text one small substring at a time; but it can be confusing)

The easy fix then (assuming this is indeed the problem), would be to call fflush(stdout) (or printf("\n"); after you call printf() to print the received text.  (Or if you are using C++ streams, call cout.flush() or cout<<endl after your call to cout << theText)

Comment: I client is written in java and already works for (java <-> java) or (c <-> java) if I use simple read() and write() methods.

Answer (score 0):

Found the error, thanks Jeremy Friesner who mentioned the client. I read until "\n" occurs -> parse message. For testing my c++ server, I have sent messages without "\n". Thank you